# Replying to an email with PHPmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPmailer and i want to reply to an email.  I fetch emails with phpimap along with their `message_id`.  I'm using PHPmailer to try and reply to an email.  I have used the `message_id` along with `In-Reply-To` in `addCustomHeader`.  I run the code and when i check the email, it is showing up as a new message and not a reply.  Where did i go wrong?

```
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

            $mail = new PHPMailer;

            //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.co.uk';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'test@domain.co.uk';                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'testing';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

            $mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
            $mail->addAddress('test_2@domain.co.uk');     // Add a recipient
            $mail->isHTML(true);                          // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', $message_id);
            $mail->Sender = 'test@domain.co.uk';
            $mail->Subject = 'testing';
            $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

            if(!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                echo 'Message has been sent';
            }
```

Comment: Email will go as reply if subject is same

Comment: Do i have to add `Re:` infront of the subject and do i have to add the previous messages or does the mail client do both of these automatically?

Comment: You just need to keep the subject same and rest will be done by email client

Comment: I've made the subject the identical but still showing up as new message.  Can you spot in my code what i did wrong or missing?

Comment: @madforstrength: wrong. It's nothing to do with the subject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's quite reasonable to have every message in a thread using a different subject line, so threading is only dependent on the subject line as a last-resort fallback if you're doing everything else wrong. It's actually quite annoying when clients do this as you end up with unrelated messages that happen to have the same subject grouped together.

Threading and replies are implemented using the `References` and `In-Reply-To` headers [as defined in RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.4). Read [this guide](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) for a thorough description of how to do threading reliably.

The short version is this, for the first reply to a message:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', $message_id);
$mail->addCustomHeader('References', $message_id);
```

It gets more complex if the original message is just the latest in a long thread, but it uses the same headers - read the spec and the guide for more info.

Make sure your message ID is correctly formatted - it should be surrounded by `<>`, like `<d7751ea969c01cda464ebf2de2fe64e6@example.org>`.

You don't need to do anything to the subject line - though it's common to prepend `Re:` , it's not necessary for the linkage to work, and it also varies  across languages, so it's not something you can rely on.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Just to be clear, if there is 4 messages, i'd have to add 4 `$message_id` to `References` or just the latest `$message_id`?

Comment: Yes, just add them on, maintaining order. It's common to drop some of them if it starts geting too long, usually ones in the middle, as you usually want to to be able to get to recent replies or the root of the thread. That guide discusses this.

Comment: Thanks, you've been great help!

Comment: My recent experience with Gmail is that subject **does** matter (emails did not come as replies when the subject changed beyond adding "re:") - and including only the most recent msg id worked fine. I'm sure this behaviour is subject to change and probably depends on the mail client so best to learn and abide by the spec, but just thought I'd share my experience.